# NSTextView paste

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a problem with paste url in custom NSTextView (where i didn't override the paste method).
When i drag drop a link from safari or from chrome to my NSTextView everything work fine but when i copy paste url from address bar to my NSTextView from safari that was not detect as an hyperlink and from chrome that was detect as hyperlink but when i click on it that didn't open the link...

If you have an idea how to solve this difference between drag and drop and copy paste (like a special override of paste method of my custom NSTextView or other) thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you switch on Smart Links?

Comment: That wasn't but i change it in xib and that change nothing... :s

Comment: Does it work if you paste and type a space?

Comment: No that don't work... That was really strange that from chrome that was detect as hyperlink but not working and as plein text from safari, really i didn't understand.